# How setup OpenId redirect uri in .NET Core 5 behind reverse proxy or loadbalance

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-core-5.0

I developed an app in .NET Core 5 using the OpenIdConnect library (6.0.12.0). On the Azure portal I have correctly configured the redirect uri with https protocol. I have 2 endpoints set up pointing to localhost and production url.

However, the production URL is under reverse proxy. When I try to access the account, I am redirected to the binding set on the IIS (e.g. `https://10.20.0.12:666/signin-oidc`) and not to the URL managed by the reverse proxy: `https://example.com/signin-oidc`.

This is part of my code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');

    services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
            .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();
```

I try to set :

```
        services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
        {
            options.Events.OnRedirectToIdentityProvider = async context =>
            {
                context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = "https://example.com/signin-oidc";
                await Task.FromResult(0);
            };
        });
```

I was looking for a complete example, can anyone help me?

Comment: in my humble opinion, the redirect url is used for OIDC to redirect the sign in platform page to our own web app, so that we should set up the redirect url which is accessible for the identity platform and the url should be able to used to reach our web page, so that we need to set `https://example.com/xxxx` both in Azure AD portal and in our app. By the way, I don't think we need to set `context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri =` in our code,

Comment: And in addition, if we want to redirect to the home page, we could set url like `https://example.com/home` instead of `/signin-oidc`, you could search in chatgpt to learn why the default redirect url is `/signin-oidc`..I don't think it makes too much sense...